# Objective-C initWithInt vs. numberFromInt vs. simply @number?

Tags: objective-c

Quite new to Objective-C, as I just started researching on an old macOS project for a client. One thing I noticed is that it seems when initializing/assigning an int value to an NSNumber object in Objective-C, there are different ways to do it, for example:

```
NSNumber *a = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10];
NSNumber *b = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:10];
NSNumber *c = @10;
```

As far as I can see, they all do the same thing, and the last line is the easiest to type and read, while the second line is just way too convoluted IMHO, so I'm just wondering are there any real differences in the end results from those three different methods, or situations where one specific method should be used because the others won't work?

Comment: They are essentially the same. Both `a` & `c` will eventually become `b` (one thing to note though is that `@` literals - which by the way works with strings, dictionaries, arrays, and books [YES|NO] also - introduced in LLVM 4.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `a` & `b` which was important before ARC when memory management was manual, but today with automatic memory management is essentially irrelevant to the programmer as ARC handles the difference seamlessly.

In pre-ARC days `a` references a number object which is not owned, while `b` references one which is owned, and the manual management required for each is different and the programmer needs to know that.

In post-ARC days the management is automatic and the programmer generally does not need to know the difference.

Option `c` is a shorthand for `a` that was introduced later and is now the standard way of creating `NSNumber` objects from literal values. The form `@(<expr>)` is also provided to create an object from the result of evaluating an *<expr>*.